# How to draw a dot within oval shape

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview

I am doing one game app. In that app one coin have to move through the views. But I don't know how to do it.

My code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="oval" >
<gradient
    android:angle="135"
    android:centerColor="#C4A5A5"
    android:endColor="#875050"
    android:startColor="#875050" />
<stroke
    android:width="1dp"
    android:color="#781A1A"
    />
</shape>
```

And my UI is:

[image]

I want to move a coin through this images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use This code........

```
    RoundRectShape rs = new RoundRectShape(new float[] { 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15 }, null, null);
    ShapeDrawable sd = new ShapeDrawable(rs);


    Button btnlogin = new Button(NativeCosmosActivity.this);
    btnlogin.setBackgroundDrawable(sd);// this line converts Button to Ovel shape.. If you increase value 15 to 30,
// you will get more Ovel shape.
```